Why has an inference site a different effect between between a direct access and when returned by a function
Take the following code :
declare class BaseClass<TValue = any> {
  value: TValue;
  foo(value: TValue): void;
}

type Wrapped<T> = { value: T }

declare class ConcreteClasss<TValue> extends BaseClass<TValue> {
  constructor(value: Wrapped<TValue> | TValue);

  override foo(value: TValue | Wrapped<TValue>): void;
}

const valuesOf = <V>(base: BaseClass<V>): V => base.value;


const base = new ConcreteClasss('Alma');
    //^?

const value = base.value;
    //^? string

const value2 = valuesOf(base);
    //^? string | Wrapped<string>

Playground
Obviously, the foo method is used a an inference site (why not).
But why is the type of value different when it's access via a helper function ?

For valuesOf you're not looking at ConcreteClass["value"] anymore; you're looking at ConcreteClass<string> extends BaseClass<infer V> ? V : never;... you're not asking TS to care about the value property.  If you want valuesOf to care about the value property you should write  <B extends BaseClass<any>>(base: B): B['value'] => base.value.  Does that make sense and fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Yeah, you can make that an answer, thank you :)

When you call valuesOf(base), TypeScript needs to infer V by treating a value of type ConcreteClass<string> as a value of type BaseClass<V>. It's essentially the same as type V = ConcreteClass<string> extends BaseClass<infer V> ? V : never.  This is string | Wrapped<string> because, as you said, TypeScript infers V from foo (and probably because methods are bivariant in their parameters? If you defined foo as a function property instead of a method then the inference would almost certainly be invariant and you'd get string. But I'm considering this out of scope for the question as asked).  The types no longer remember ConcreteClass<T> at all; such information has been thrown away. So even though the implementation of valuesOf writes base.value, the only type available for that is V, which is string | WrappedString<T>.
If you want valuesOf(base) to return the actual type of base.value, you need to make the function generic in the type of base, like:
const valuesOf =
  <B extends BaseClass<any>>(base: B): B['value'] => base.value

I've annotated the return type of the function to use the indexed access type B['value'], otherwise you're likely to get BaseClass<any>['value'] or any, because TS widens specific indexes into generic objects to the constraint, see microsoft/TypeScript#33181.
Now you get
const value2 = valuesOf(base);
//    ^? const value2: string;

as desired.
Playground link to code
